# Is f(g(x)) is Riemann integrable?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Assume f and g are Riemann integrable on [0,1].  Determine if f(g(x)) is Riemann integrable.  Find a counterexample if you answered no.
I'm pretty sure that they aren't Riemann integrable but I'm having trouble coming up with a counterexample.

Comment: See http://mathoverflow.net/q/20045/31729.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Recall that $f(g(x))$ will be Riemann-integrable precisely when it is continuous except on a set of measure zero.  There is no particular reason to expect this property to be closed under composition.
We set $f(x)$ to be the indicator function for the singleton set $\{0\}$, namely:
$$f(x) = \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
1 & x = 0\\
0 & \text{ otherwise}
\end{array}
\right.
$$
It is clear that $f$ is continuous except for a removable discontinuity at $x=0$.

We can  then set 
$$g(x) = \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
\frac{1}{q} & x\in \Bbb Q, x = \frac{p}{q} \text{ where } p,q \text{ are relatively prime}\\
0 & x\not\in \Bbb Q
\end{array}
\right.
$$
It is a standard exercise to show that $g(x)$ is continuous at all irrational points. This implies that $g(x)$ is Riemann-integrable as well.

We can  see that 
$$f(g(x)) = \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
1 & x\not\in \Bbb Q\\
0 & x\in \Bbb Q
\end{array}
\right.
$$
This is now discontinuous at all points, and thus not Riemann-integrable.